# How to programmatically scroll UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have implemented to a page to display multiple Viewcontroller via UIPageViewController.  User can scroll horizontally to view a different ViewController  (And I have dynamic number of VCs, depending on the data loaded from server) .

The problem is most of the user does not know that they can scroll horizontally . I would like to show to user when they come to my app first time that the page is horizontally scrollable. Just like the screenshot below

[image: half-scroll]

The easiest way is to show them the half-page scroll first so they realize that this page is scrollable.  But I have searched through SO and found none of the solution.  If I add gesture programmatically, the app might got rejected from appstore. So are there any easy way to do this?

Comment: The app won't get rejected if you add a gesture programatically.

Just modify your UI add a small left and right arrow to indicate they can scroll.

Comment: Glad to see a Thai here. I'm Thai as well. I agree with @artud2000. Why not just add an overlay showing arrows and telling the user they can scroll horizontally?

Comment: If I want to include the right arrow to the UI ,I would not ask it on SO here.